# Geting new versionId on marklogic node.js write with versionId

Tags: node.js, marklogic, optimistic-locking

Is it possible to obtain new versionId when modifying a document with Optimist locking enabled without performing a read after write?
At https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/documents#id_26261 the success data doesn't containt the new versionId.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question but, unfortunately, at present it isn't possible to return the version id after an update.

You can perform a probe (the equivalent of a HEAD request in the Node.js API), which should be slightly less expensive than a read (the equivalent of a GET request in the Node.js API).

You may want to have your customer support contact file an RFE (Request For Enhancement) to return the versionId after write.